# SIP Websocket Client implementation in C++

Tags: c++, websocket, sip

I need to implement a SIP websocket client using c++. I have npm SIP websocket server. I want to test the connection using c/c++. Is there any easy to use libraries available to implement SIP websocket client in c/c++ ?

Answer (score 0):

If course there is. Have a look at [WebSocket++](http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp).

As to exactly how to do it - I wouldn't know since I don't know the SIP protocol. But I'll venture a guess that you need to use binary frames in WebSocket. The server, which you say already exists, obviously has implemented it - and its documentation should contain some information on how to interface with it.